# Printing Bit map image to TM-P60 thermal printer via serial port

Tags: c#, printing, bitmap, epson

With a reference to this link ([Printing a Bit map image to pos printer via comport in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099239/printing-a-bit-map-image-to-pos-printer-via-comport-in-c-sharp)) I am facing difficulties to print a bitmap image on Epson TM-P60 (print density 203 dpi x 203 dpi and printing width is 420 dot position)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This link can be helpful: [link](http://www.bluestarinc.com/techsupport/epson/TM_P60/TMT88II_T88III_P60_DG_RevA.pdf)

Comment: This [article](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/12/sending-a-bit-image-to-an-epson-tm-t88iii-receipt-printer-using-c-and-escpos/) by Nicholas Piasecki, should help