# print image using ESC POS commands Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, printing, command, escpos

I'm trying print image date using ESC POS commands in Javascript, but until now just crap is printing out.

Command ESC *

I'm using Javascript, trying print direct to bluethoo a image in bit64string.

[I tried this example with ESC @, ESC * command in Javscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099239/printing-a-bit-map-image-to-pos-printer-via-comport-in-c-sharp)

It only prints me characters, but not the image

Thank in advance

```
 // let image = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height)
  getImageData(image, Width, Height){

     var dimensions = Width * Height
     var dots = new Uint8Array(dimensions)
     var index = 0
     var threshold = 127;
     for (var y = 0; y < Height; y++)
     {         
         for (var x = 0; x < Width; x++)
         {             
            var color =   this.getPixelI(image, x, y)           
            //let luminance  
            let luminance =  (0.2126* color[0] + 0.7152 * color[1] + 0.0722 * color[2]);
            dots[index] = luminance < threshold              
            index++;
         }
     }      
     return dots
  }

 getPixelI(imgData, x, y) {   
    var i = y * (imgData.width * 4) + x * 4;    
    var d = imgData.data;

    return [d[i],d[i+1],d[i+2], d[i+3]]  // returns array [R,G,B,A]
  }
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, any news?

Comment: nothing my friend